# Prove that $\log_a(b)=-\log_b(a)$

Tags: logarithms

Can you prove that:
$$\log_a(b)=-\log_b(a)$$
I just thought that it should equal $$\frac{\log(b)}{\log(a)}.$$
but I don't think anything else.

Comment: Let $log_a (b)=x$ then $a^x=b$ then $b^{-x}=a$ so that $log_b(a)=-x$

Comment: @corciacandy: No, $b^{-x} = (a^x)^{-x} = a^{-x^2} \ne a$ unless $x=0$ and $a=1$.

Comment: Actually @celtschk is true. That statement is false. Think a=b=10

Comment: @corciacandy In that case it's $b^{1/x}=a$.

Comment: @Arthur: But $1/x\ne -x$

Comment: @Arthur  my solution is wrong ok you are right

Answer (score 5):

$\log_a(b) = \frac{\log b}{\log a} = \frac{1}{\frac{\log a}{\log b}} = \frac{1}{\log_b(a)} ≠ -\log_b(a)$ in general.

Comment: Just to be a bit clearer, if both $a$ and $b$ are greater than $1$, then both logarithms are _positive_.

Comment: Yes. There are infinitely many counter-examples to this claim.

Comment: Indeed, there are *only* counterexamples to the claim: There are no real numbers $a$, $b$ such that $\log_ab=-\log_ba$.

Answer (score 1):

let $$\log_a(b) = x \to b = a^x\to a= b^{1/x}\to \log_b(a) = \frac 1x=\frac1{\log_b(a)}$$ you can rewrite this as $$\log_a(b)\log_b(a) = 1.$$

in general we have the change of basis formula$$\log_a(b)\log_b(c) = \log_a(c).$$ the previous identity is the special case of $c = a.$